# Does the Windows "more" command line utility append a newline to the end of the file it displays?

Tags: command-line, bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

I have an input file containing one arithmetic expression on each line. The file has this form:

```
expr EOL expr EOL expr
```

The last arithmetic expression isn't followed by an end-of-line (EOL).

The file may contain just one arithmetic expression, in which case it has this form:

```
expr
```

I wrote a parser to evaluate the first line, output the result, then repeat for the remaining lines. The name of my parser is: `calc`.

The input file (`test.txt`) contains this:

```
5 + 3 * 2 - 10
2 + 3 * 4
```

When I execute the parser this way:

```
calc test.txt
```

I get the correct output:

```
1
14
```

When I use the "`more`" command on `test.txt` and pipe it to `calc`:

```
more test.txt | calc
```

I get this result:

```
1
14
3: syntax error
```

Why am I getting that syntax error?

I noticed that I also get the syntax error with this way of involving calc:

```
calc test.txt
```

when I manually add a newline at the end of the last line (recall that my parser expects no newline after the last expression).

Does the "`more`" command add a newline to the end of the file it displays? If so, is there a way to prevent "`more`" from doing that?

Note: I am doing this from a command line on Windows 10.

Below is my lexer and parser.

**Lexer:**

```
%option noyywrap
%option always-interactive
%option yylineno
%{
#include "parse.tab.h"
%}
%% 
[0-9]+      { yylval.str_val = strdup(yytext); return NUMBER; }
"+"         { return('+');                                    }
"-"         { return('-');                                    }
"*"         { return('*');                                    }
"/"         { return('/');                                    }
\n          { return(EOL);                                    }
[ ]+        { /* discard whitespace */                        }
%%
```

**Parser:**

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/* interface to the lexer */
extern int yylineno; /* from lexer */
int yylex(void);

void yyerror(const char *s, ...);
extern FILE *yyin;
int yyparse (void);
%}
%union {
   char *str_val;
   int int_val;
}
%token<str_val> NUMBER
%token<str_val> EOL
%type<int_val> expr
%type<int_val> top
%type<int_val> initial_expressions
%type<int_val> final_expression
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'
%%
top: initial_expressions final_expression   { }
  ;
  
initial_expressions: %empty             { }
  |   initial_expressions expr EOL      { fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", $2); }
  ;
  
final_expression: expr                  { fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", $1); }
  ;

expr: NUMBER        { $$ = atoi($1); }
  | expr '+' expr   { $$ = $1 + $3;  }
  | expr '-' expr   { $$ = $1 - $3;  }
  | expr '*' expr   { $$ = $1 * $3;  }
  | expr '/' expr   { $$ = $1 / $3;  }
;
%%

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
    yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    yyparse();
    fclose(yyin);
    return 0;
}

void yyerror(const char *s, ...)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "%d: %s\n", yylineno, s);
}
```

Comment: You've overcomplicated this. Why don't you just allow the file to end with an EOL like most files do, and avoid the whole problem? You probably don't need EOL as part of the grammar at all: just treat it as whitespace. And you certainly don't need `initial_expressions` or `final_expression`. They are all just expressions.

Comment: EOL at the end of the last line in a widely used convention, especially in programs originating from Unix-like systems. Some of them won't work if the EOL is missing and most of them will add it to the output even if it is not in the input. My advice would be to not make assumptions about any whitespaces. No assuming ` ` / `\t`, no `LF` / `CRLF` and especially no whether there is an EOL at the end. (There are editors like `vim` which don't even allow not having an EOL.)

Comment: The question is about `more` so I won't put it as an answer but you could change your EOL rule in lex to `\n/.` (new line followed by another character) and add another rule with just `\n` which doesn't return any token. That would allow ignoring the last EOL character if it is not followed by anything. Less dirty solution, that gracefully handles all whitespaces, would require changes in parser and is too long for a comment.

Comment: Well it isn't really too long for a comment: it is to do what I already said and change the target rule to `top : /* empty */ | top expr ;`.